# Using margin on wrap list won't work. margin: top is always 0

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/MqPDH/10/

Why does the 1st wrap `.wp-list` `margin: 10px`  and `.a` `.b` use `margin: 10px` not work?

```
.wp{
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 450px;
}
.wp_list{
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 130px;
    position:relative;
}
.a, .b, .c{
    background-color: gray;
}
.a{
    width: 220px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.b{
    width: 220px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.c{
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wp">
    <div class="wp_list">
        <div class="a">a</div>
        <div class="b">b</div>
        <div class="c">c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wp_list">
        <div class="a">a</div>
        <div class="b">b</div>
        <div class="c">c</div>
    </div>
    // generate from php
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vertical margins may collapse on block level elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins), this means that when you have an element with a `10px` margin set on the bottom, followed by an element with `5px` margin set on the top. The margin between the two will not be `15px`, but will collapse down to the largest of the two: `10px`, or in this case when they're both `10px`, it will collapse to be `10px`.

You should add `display: inline-block;` to `.a, .b, .c`, that will fix it:

```
.a, .b, .c{
    background-color: gray;
    display: inline-block;  
}
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MqPDH/11/)</kbd>

Comment: Collapse on Block Elements?

Comment: @Starx - Yes, that's what I am saying: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins, I'll add the link and change my wording to "vertical margins" in my post to make it more clear. But I can't read anything else into what the spec says, it also seems to behave like for OP *and* fix OP's problem.

Comment: I dont think block elements collapse. Inline Element's collapse their margin.

Comment: @Starx - But it is about what the spec says? Not about what you think?

Comment: @Starx - Quote from W3 spec: In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined margin is called a collapsed margin. Two margins are adjoining if and only if: both belong to in-flow block-level boxes that participate in the same block formatting context. I don't know what else I could make of this?

Comment: The link you attached says in flow block elements, I am confused. `inline-block` and `block` make a element behave like a block, but if what you saying about block element collapsing is right, then margin should be collapsing when we define display: inline-block.

Comment: @Starx - "In flow" meaning "not absolutely positioned"? It makes sense  to me.

Comment: If you click on the linked text in the spec "block-level boxes", it defines a "block-level box" like this: Block-level elements are those elements of the source document that are formatted visually as blocks (e.g., paragraphs). The following values of the 'display' property make an element block-level: 'block', 'list-item', and 'table'.

Answer (score 1):

This is mainly because because it is behaving as inline element. Add `display: inline-block;`

```
.wp_ist{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 130px;
    position:relative;
}
```